# Triggering function on Xamarin.Forms Entry Focused/Unfocused

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

**Original problem:** I want to call a function each time the soft keyboard is shown/hidden on my Xamarin.Forms ContentPage.

One option was to use a custom renderer where I have access to the keyboard observers. I haven't tried this yet; I thought I'd try banging my head with other approaches first.

**Approach 1)** Assign event handler to the Focused/Unfocused events of all entries on my page which trigger a keyboard show/hide, in the page's code-behind as follows:

```
EventHandler<FocusEventArgs> keyboard_handler = (object sender, FocusEventArgs e) => 
{
    var binding_context = BindingContext as MyViewModel;
    binding_context?.OnKeyboardShowing();
};
PasswordEntry.Focused += keyboard_handler; // doesn't trigger keyboard_handler
PasswordEntry.Unfocused += keyboard_handler; // doesn't trigger
UsernameEntry.Focused += keyboard_handler; // triggers
UsernameEntry.Unfocused += keyboard_handler; //doesn't trigger
```

**Question 1**: Why don't some of those trigger?

**Approach 2)** Use `EventTriggers` along with a custom `TriggerAction<Entry>` class, as follows:

Part of the XAML file showing one of the entries (which is in a grid, in a StackLayout in a ScrollView in a Grid, if you must know):

```
<Entry Grid.Row="0"
       x:Name="UsernameEntry"
       Margin="0,2"
       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
       Placeholder="User"
       IsVisible="{Binding UsernameEnabled}"
       Completed="Username_Completed"
       IsEnabled="{Binding EnableControls}"
       Text="{Binding Username, Mode=TwoWay}" >
    <Entry.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger Event="Focused">
            <local:FocusedAction />
        </EventTrigger>
    </Entry.Triggers>
</Entry>
```

And the `TriggerAction<Entry>` class defined in the code-behind:

```
public class FocusedAction : TriggerAction<Entry>
{
    protected override void Invoke(Entry entry)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Reached"); // Except it never reaches here.
    }
}
```

**Question 2:** Why doesn't `Invoke` up there ever get triggered?

Am I missing something in my XAML, code-behind or somewhere else? I've checked the Xamarin docs, but as always, I've found them less than useless.

Comment: what is the expected behavior you looking for?

Comment: Nevermind. A clean/build fixed the issue. V.Studio really needs to sort this s&^% out. We can't seriously be expected to perform a clean each time something doesn't work with Xamarin.

Comment: If nothing I suppose this could serve as an example demonstrating how to trigger a function when focus changes on an entry. Caveat: may need clean/build.

Comment: Half of issues with any .NET solutions are solved by cleaning Debug and rebuilding :).